# Find and return an if code block from a file

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a bash script to find if a code block starting with 
`if (isset($conf['memcache_servers'])) {` exists in a file?

If true, then I need to return the whole if block.

How to do that?

**Code block return example:**

```
if (isset($conf['memcache_servers'])) {
   $conf['cache_backends'][] = '.memcache.inc';
   $conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCache';
   $conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DatabaseCache';
 }
```

Comment: You want to find a line starting with that and then all content until when? That looks like perl code, which is notoriously hard to parse. The "till when" bit might be quite hard to pin down if it is just "complete code block and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` to do this. From a `bash` command line, run this:

```
sed -n "/if (isset(\$conf\['memcache_servers'\]))/,/}/p" inputFile
```

This uses range option `/pattern1/,/pattern2/` from `sed`, and `p` to print everything between and including the `if...{` and `}` lines.

Here, I have used double quotes to express the sed script because the first pattern includes single quotes`'`. he sqaure-brackets need to be escaped as well. `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I wanted. Appreciate your help!